# Passing parameters to stored procedure for an UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I've been trying to convert to using stored procedures in SQL Server to do our CRUD. In my code-behind here, this is how I pass the parameters to the `SqlHelper` class (If you need to me to post this as well, let me know). But is this blocking SQL injection? Is there a better way to pass these? I've also pasted my Stored Procedure for my update below this. Any recommendations for improving this would be appreciated!

```
protected void UpdateRecord()
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[19];

    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@empfk", empno.Text);
    sqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@prescriptpk", TxtPK.Text);
    sqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@date", TxtDate.Text);
    sqlParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@arcfk", DDLFullName.SelectedValue);
    sqlParam[4] = new SqlParameter("@OT", chkOT.Checked);
    sqlParam[5] = new SqlParameter("@PT", chkPT.Checked);
    sqlParam[6] = new SqlParameter("@PS", chkPS.Checked);
    sqlParam[7] = new SqlParameter("@SA", chkSA.Checked);
    sqlParam[8] = new SqlParameter("@EC", chkEC.Checked);
    sqlParam[9] = new SqlParameter("@NC", chkNC.Checked);
    sqlParam[10] = new SqlParameter("@reason", DDLReason.SelectedValue);
    sqlParam[11] = new SqlParameter("@sentto", TxtSentTo.Text);
    sqlParam[12] = new SqlParameter("@sentvia", DDLSentVia.SelectedValue);
    sqlParam[13] = new SqlParameter("@datereceived", TxtDateRec.Text);
    sqlParam[14] = new SqlParameter("@datesigned", txtDateSigned.Text);
    sqlParam[15] = new SqlParameter("@comments", txtComments.Text);
    sqlParam[16] = new SqlParameter("@effbeg", TxtEffBeg.Text);
    sqlParam[17] = new SqlParameter("@effend", TxtEffEnd.Text);
    sqlParam[18] = new SqlParameter("@documentation", txtDocumentation.Text);

    sqlhelper.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "prescriptions_Update", sqlParam);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prescriptions_Update]
    (@prescriptpk int, @date date, @arcfk int, @OT bit, 
     @PT bit, @PS bit, @SA bit, @EC bit, @NC bit, 
     @reason varchar(30), @sentto varchar(40), 
     @sentvia char(10), @datereceived date, @datesigned date, 
     @comments varchar(max), @effbeg date, @effend date,
     @documentation varchar(max) )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    UPDATE [Support].[dbo].[prescriptions] 
    SET [date] = @date, arcfk = @arcfk, OT = @OT, PT = @PT, PS = @PS, 
        SA = @SA, EC = @EC, NC = @NC, reason = @reason, sentto = @sentto, 
        sentvia = @sentvia, datereceived = @datereceived, 
        datesigned = @datesigned, comments = @comments, effbeg = @effbeg, 
        effend = @effend, documentation = @documentation 
    WHERE 
        prescriptpk = @prescriptpk
END
GO
```

Comment: Yes this looks properly parameterized and safe from sql injection.

Comment: @user1911069 you are using the Parameters incorrectly there is a much simpler way to do this by using the `SQLCommand.Parameters.Add` method also there is an easier way to add parameters using a loop if you want a posted example of how to do this in a custom class let me know and I will be happy to post

Comment: That would be great. I used the SQLCommand.Parameters.Add in my previous code for SQL injection but couldn't figure out how to pass that in the Sqlhelper class. Do I even need that class?

Comment: I deleted the Answer since it's obvious people don't read here.. just convert what you are trying to do into a Method and pass the parameters as an array in your case it would be `SqlParameters[] params` good luck

Comment: @SeanLange Is it properly parameterized in my stored procedure or is the sqlhelper class doing the work? Thanks

Comment: Your procedure is parameterized as it should be. The trick is not doing dynamic sql and not directly executing user input. Your procedure is doing that part correctly. As mentioned you could streamline your dotnet code .

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has an article that you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It goes over what you need to do to prevent SQL injection.

But the summary of the article is that you need to use `SqlCommand` and `AddWithValue`.

Comment: And AddWithValue can sometimes get things wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @MethodMan Where did you read that? I'm almost certain `AddWithValue` is not deprecated. It still comes up as valid in VS and I searched online, but found nothing.

Comment: @ernest2 what version of .Net are you using .. and yes it's `Depricated` read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MethodMan I just tried it on 4.6. VS doesn't say it's deprecated and I searched online, but found nothing that says it's deprecated.

Comment: @ernest just because it's Depricated does not mean you can't use it however if you read the MSDN Remarks you will see what I am talking about. Cheers

Comment: @MethodMan The article you linked says that `Add` has been deprecated. `AddWithValue` is ideal. "AddWithValue replaces the **SqlParameterCollection.Add** method..." "The overload of Add that takes a string and an object was **deprecated**"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private static SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection();
private static SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand();
private static SqlConnection _Conn = new SqlConnection();

private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
            _Connection.ConnectionString = "ConnectionString";
            _Connection.Open();
            }
            return _Connection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

public static void UpdateData(params object[] ParamValue)
    {
        try
        {
            _Conn = GetConnection();
            _Command.Connection = _Conn;
            _Command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            _Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            _Command.CommandText = "updateprocedure";

            _Command.Parameters.Clear();
            _Command.Parameters.Add("@Paramname1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ParamValue[0];
            _Command.Parameters.Add("@Paramname2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ParamValue[1];
            _Command.Parameters.Add("@Paramname3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ParamValue[2];


            _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```